# How can i identify if user is admin or not in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

Good day,

i am trying to make a login system where both the client and the admin can log in. If the user is an admin then he/she will be redirected to the admin panel if not then the user will be redirected to the home page of the webshop. I am struggling a little with the logic for authentication. I am trying to identify wether the user is logged in. if the/she is then i authenticate the user role by checking if 'isAdmin' is true or false. I do this by finding the user in the database by looking for the isAdmin state. I am using jwt tokens to get the state of the user.

Authentication:

```
const { verify } = require("jsonwebtoken");
const userModel = require("../model/userModel");

// const isAuth = req => {
//  const authorization = req.headers["authorization"];
//  if (!authorization) throw new Error("You need to login");
//  const token = authorization.split(" ")[1];
//  const { userId } = verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
//  return userId;
// };

const isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied");
    //verifying the token then  sending the id back of the user
    try {
        const verified = verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send("Invalid");
    }
};

//isAdmin
const isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send("No User");
    try {
        const verified = verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        let user = await userModel.findOne({ isAdmin });
        if (req.user && user.isAdmin === true) {
            return next();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(401).send({ msg: "Admin token is not valid" });
    }
};

//check user
// const checkUser = (req, res, next) => {
//  //get token from cookies
//  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
//  //check if token exists
//  if (token) {
//      verify(token, process.env.SECRET, async (err, decode) => {
//          if (err) {
//              console.log(err.message);
//              next();
//              res.locals.user = null;
//          } else {
//              console.log(decode);
//              next();
//              let user = await userModel.findOne(decode.isAdmin);
//              res.local.user = user;
//              next();
//          }
//      });
//  } else {
//  }
// };

module.exports = {
    isAuth,
    isAdmin,
};
```

Route:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) res.send({ error: "User does not exists" });
    const validPass = await compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validPass) {
        return res.json({ error: "email or password is incorrect" });
    }

    
    const token = sign(
        { _id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin },
        process.env.SECRET,
        {
            expiresIn: "24h",
        },
    );
    res.header("auth-token", token).send({
        token,
        email: req.body.email,
        id: user._id,
    });

    
});


router.get("/adminPanel", isAdmin, isAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        title: "ADMIN PANEL",
    });
});
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: @rveerd   identifying the admin

Comment: You don't need to use both the `isAdmin` and the `isAuth` middlewares. Actualy isAuth is just enough since You can check if user is admin in the isAuth middleware, the token has the information. So try to remove isAdmin from the route and in the isAuth try console.log('Am i admin? :', verified.isAdmin);

Comment: Also this `let user = await userModel.findOne({ isAdmin });` is unlikely to work the way you want.  This `{ isAdmin }` is shortcut for `{ isAdmin: isAdmin }` the problem here is that the isAdmin is a function `const isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {` Did you mean to use `{ isAdmin: verified.isAdmin }`? Although even this wouldn't work since you will only find the first user which is admin not necessarily the one you think. You should use _id instead like so `let user = await userModel.findOneById(verified._id);` BUT as i said you don't need the isAdmin middleware at all.

Answer (score 1):

Code based on my comments bellow your question

```
const { verify } = require("jsonwebtoken");
const userModel = require("../model/userModel");

const isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied");

    try {
        const verified = verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        console.log('Am i admin?', req.user.isAdmin);
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send("Invalid token");
    }
};

const isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {

    // no need to verify token again
    // the `req.user.isAdmin` is already available from isAuth
    // also no need to query a database, we have all the info we need from the token
    if (!req.user.isAdmin)
        return res.status(401).send({ msg: "Not an admin, sorry" });

    next();
};

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const user = findUserSomehow();
    
    const token = sign({ _id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin }, process.env.SECRET, { expiresIn: "24h" });

    res.header("auth-token", token).send({
        token,
        email: req.body.email,
        id: user._id,
    });    
});

// notice the order of middlewares, isAuth first
router.get("/adminPanel", isAuth, isAdmin, (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        title: "ADMIN PANEL",
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. One more question how would i logout the user? by removing the header with the auth-token?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not very familiar with jwt tokens, so it's hard to tell. But it's certainly one way to do it. It depends on where/how you store the jwt token on the client side.